# js calculating total price from input number and show

Tags: javascript

I have three types for tickets. Children - cost 8$, retirees - cost 10$ and adults - cost 12$ and i have 3 input numbers and i want when someone of these three input change to calculate and print in html total price

This is my html

```
children<input type="number" id="children" name="children" min="0" max="20" value="0" onchange="myScript">
adults<input type="number" id="adults" name="adults" min="0" max="20" value="0" onchange="myScript">
retirees<input type="number" id="retirees" name="retirees" min="0" max="20" value="0" >
```

This is my js

```
function totalPrice(){
   var total = 0 
   var children = document.getElementsByName('children');
   var children = document.getElementsByName('adults');
   var children = document.getElementsByName('retirees');
   total = (parseInt(children) * 8) + (parseInt(adults) * 12) + (parseInt(retirees) * 10);

Here i dont know how to print in html total price
```

I want to look something like that

[image]

Comment: [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is what you are looking for

Comment: Not sure if it is a typo, but you have all three variables named `children`

Comment: getElementsByName -> get value here you are storing full element, see my solution in post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to place a `div` for displaying Total in html

```
<div id="total"></div>
```

then attach an "eventListener" for `change` to each input field to trigger the calculation

```
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("change", () => {
    totalPrice();
  });
});
```

then update the value in html with:

```
totalDiv.innerHTML = `<h3>Total: ${total}$</h3>`;
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-sre3cr?file=index.js)

Comment: I try to make it like yours, but didnt work for me. Do you know is it problem to use jsp instead html

Comment: Cany you share the jsp page?

Comment: Move this line `<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/totalPrice.js"></script>` from top to just before `</body>` line.  Last 3 lines to be `<script ....` then `</body>` then `</html>`

Comment: pastebin what you have in this file: `totalPrice.js`

Comment: remove lines: 1, 2 (import style.css) and 10, 11 and 12 (write javascript code...)

Comment: I need help for one last js fuction, can u help me

Comment: Sure, update the question or ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Given a div below the `<inputs>`, in the form of `<div id="price"></div>`

You could set the price this way:

```
let price_div = document.querySelector("#price")
// Apply whatever formatting to the price you want.
price_div.innerHTML = total
```

Answer (score 0):

As these are **input fields** you can just use their **value**

```
function totalPrice(){
   var total = 0 
   var children = document.getElementsByName('children');
   var adults = document.getElementsByName('adults');
   var retirees = document.getElementsByName('retirees');
   total = (parseInt(children.value) * 8) + (parseInt(adults.value) * 12) + (parseInt(retirees.value) * 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
          function totalPrice(){
       var total = 0 
       var children = document.getElementsByName('children')[0].value;
       var adults = document.getElementsByName('adults')[0].value;
       var retirees = document.getElementsByName('retirees')[0].value;
       total = (children * 8) + (adults * 12) + (retirees * 10);
       console.log(total);
       document.getElementById('totalPrice').textContent=total;
       
       }
```

```html
  children <input type="number" id="children" name="children" min="0" max="20" value="0" onKeyUp="totalPrice()">
    adults <input type="number" id="adults" name="adults" min="0" max="20" value="0" onKeyUp="totalPrice()">
    retirees <input type="number" id="retirees" name="retirees" min="0" max="20" value="0" onKeyUp="totalPrice()">
    <div id="totalPrice" style="color:red"></div>
```

Comment: but how to make it without button